# View threads/conversations in Evolution just like Gmail can

Tags: evolution, email, gmail

I want to view threaded email conversations in Evolution. Is there a menu option for this? By threaded conversations I mean something like what Google's GMail does.

Comment: The problem with Evolution threads (compared with Gmail's) is that Evolution uses only the subject of the email for threading, regardless of the sender and the context. So, for example unrelated (even old) emails with the subject "meeting" will be threaded anyway. I think Gmail uses some heuristics to distinguish real threads.

Comment: As of Evolution 3.10 it seems that the threading improved as it is only partly based on the subject, in fact there is an option "Fall back to threading messages by subject" to get old (bad) behavior. It seems that replies are still not part of the thread unfortunately.

Comment: I would actually pay a bounty for this feature.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not exactly like in GMail but there is an option *View -> Group by Threads* or CTRL+T to group a thread in Evolution.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to look at threaded conversations by selecting the threaded view.Look at the View menu.I use CTRL+T to turn on the threaded view.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Ah I barely noticed, the threading indentation is only on the Subject column. Which in my case was not the first column, reordering the columns with drag and drop helped me.